# Fibonacci Search Comparisons: worst and average cases

Tags: algorithm, search, fibonacci

I am working on the Fibonacci Search Algorithm, and I need an optimal equation which will help to find the worst case, average case and best case comparisons.

I know the best case is always 1, but I need to find the worst case and average cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia article on the [Fibonacci search technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_search_technique) mentions:

> Compared to binary search where the sorted array is divided into two equal-sized parts, one of which is examined further, Fibonacci search divides the array into two parts that have sizes that are consecutive Fibonacci numbers. On average, this leads to about 4% more comparisons to be executed [...]
>
> Fibonacci search has an average- and worst-case complexity of *O*(log *n*).